# Filling an std::vector with raw data

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to fill a vector with raw data, sometimes 2 bytes, sometimes 8... I ended up with this template function:

```
template <typename T>
void fillVector(std::vector<uint8_t>& dest, T t)
{
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&t);
    dest.insert(dest.end(),ptr,ptr+sizeof(t));
}
```

with this I can fill the vector like this:

```
fillVector<uint32_t>(dst,32bitdata);
fillVector<uint16_t>(dst,16bitdata);
```

I was wondering if something more similar already exist in the standard library?

Comment: is it not practical to use a `std::vector` of `std::vectors`s? `std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>`

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah that. Was writing a better comment actually. So, just for posterity's sake, this is UB when `uint8_t` is not an alias to `unsigned char`, because, [as type aliasing rules state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), in this case only `byte`, `char` or `unsigned char` *permit examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.* And that could be a reason for that NOT being in the standard library.

Comment: @skratchi.at - Why?

Comment: @StoryTeller lacking information what he wants to do with it, it just came into my mind

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, sure,, I can use this just because I know that I'm always using int/uint data, simply with different sizes. I don't like this code, That's why I'm searching for something simple to push data in the vector without having to cast everytime.

Comment: @ErniBrown I'd consider implementing a view rather than a copy, then (think `string_view`). Instead of filling the vector with that data, simply provide `operator[]` (and possibly begin/end as well). Then you'll be able to fill a vector using such a wrapper view, but it will also allow you to read the data directly without any copies; it's just a more generic approach.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz interesting, I'll take this in consideration. But it seems to me that `string_view` is only available with C++17, right? Unfortunately I'm currently using a compiler which is only c++11 compliant

Comment: Also if it's only used with integers, it should really have a constraint on `std::is_integral` or similar, before someone tries to use it on some weird type.

Comment: @ErniBrown Not necessarily, no. Well, `string_view` itself is, but the idea of a reference-based wrapper object isn't.

Comment: You don't need to write `fillVector<uint32_t>(dst,32bitdata);` if `32bitdata` is of type `uint32_t`. With `fillVector(dst,32bitdata);`, a compiler will deduce `T` to `uint32_t` for you.

Comment: @DanielLangr, isn't type deduction a C++17 feature?

Comment: @ErniBrown Not at all. There are only some new features of type deduction since C++17, such as type deduction for class templates. Your case would work even before C++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's nothing in the standard library to achieve what you are after. So your solution is pretty much what you can currently go with (assuming your goal is to do some form of serialization).

The only point of improvement is that you are assuming `uint8_t` is a type that may be used to alias an object and inspect its bytes. That need not be the case. The only such types in C++11 are `char` and `unsigned char`. While `uint8_t` usually aliases the later in most modern architectures, that's not a hard requirement, it could alias a platform specific 8 bit unsigned integer type (the merits of that are outside the scope of this question). So to be standard conforming, either guard against it:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<unsigned char, std::uint8_t>::value, "Oops!");
```

Or use your own alias for valid "byte" type

```
namespace myapp { using byte = unsigned char; }
```

and deal in `std::vector<myapp::byte>`.

Comment: as you said the reasons why uint8_t may not be a char equivalent are out of the scope of this question, but I'd like to learn more about, can you point me to some discussion about this?

Comment: @ErniBrown - I don't have a link, but on one foot it's about optimizations. Compilers can often optimize more aggressively the more they can assume about the program. And using a proper integer type that can't alias other things can facilitate such optimizations more easily.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8 is an interesting if slightly esoteric read (and may not directly address your question but is related nonetheless)